# Is the inequality of my development correct?

Tags: geometry

If I have a scalene trapezoid ABCD, with L1 // L2.

[image]

In this, $a  + b + c = 180$, Now I developed a little:

[image]

So, $a + m = 180, b + k = 180$.

I need to find the inequality of $m + k$

My development was:

If $a + b + c = 180$ to form a triangle, so $a + b < 180$.

And, $(a + m) + (b + k) = 360$, because it's a four-sided polygon(trapezoid).

Since, $(a + m) + (b + k) = 360$ => $(a + b) + (m + k) = 360$, and $a + b < 180$, so $m + k$ should be:

$m + k > 180$, is correct my development and the inequality ? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Yes, it is correct.